# not able to access functions of a different class in different namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have two different namespaces

**Namespace 1**

```
namespace Project.Constants
{
   public class EducationalInstitutes
    {
       public string test() {

           return "Value";
       }
    }
}
```

**Namespace 2**

```
using Project.Constants;  //namespace 1 

namespace Project.DAL
{
   public class EducationalInstitute
    {

       EducationalInstitutes obj = new EducationalInstitutes();
          obj.


    }
}
```

The problem is the functions that i have defined in the class `EducationalInstitutes` are not available in the place where I have created object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to place your code in the bottom snippet inside a method.

You can't call methods on `obj` from that location in your class.

```
public class EducationalInstitute
{
   EducationalInstitutes obj = new EducationalInstitutes();

   public void DoSomething()
   {
       obj.test();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call method inside the method not the inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method and inside that method create the object for the **EducationalInstitutes** class. Then you can access the method in it. You can not access the method in class directly.